# Round off Float value in C without in-built functions

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic

I am writing a code for PIC microcontroller in C language. I have a float value of more than 4 decimal places. I want to round it to 1 decimal place.

But the issue is, I can't use the round,floor,ceil functions available in C language.

Is there any other way to do this mathematically?

**UPDATE 1:**

I want to display the temp on an LCD attached to a PIC microcontroller. I am simulating that the temp sensor gives 0-5V linearly for the range -40*C to 50*C.

For this, I am using linear interpolation to determine the temp. value to be shown on the LCD. Here is my function:

```
float Temp;
void Read_Temp()
{
  ADCON0 &= 0xC5;              //Clearing channel selection bits
  ADCON0 |= 0<<3;              //Setting channel 0 selection bits
  __delay_ms(2);               
  while(GO_nDONE);             
  unsigned int adc_value = ((ADRESH<<8)+ADRESL);

  Temp = (adc_value * (90.0/1023.0)) - 40.0; // to show in celcius

  if(TempMode == 'F')  // to show in farenheit
      Temp = (Temp*1.8)+32;    
}
```

I am using a library to interface the lcd. The function to display float values has this comment written alongside in it in header file:

```
/* LCD_display_float: Displays a floating point numerical value on the LCD 
 * This function take the parameter 'value' and displays it to the number of
 * decimal places specified by the parameter 'dplaces'. NOTE: The function
 * is limited to displaying 4 significant figures due to headroom limitations
 * of the 24 bit float type in MPLAB X. Attempting to display more than 4
 * significant figures will lead to the string "ERR" being displayed. */

void LCD_display_float (float value, unsigned char dplaces);
```

So when I simulate my code, ERR is written on the lcd. How should I go around this problem?

If you guys need the definition of lcd_display_float(), I can also upload that as well.

Comment: If the value doesn't exceed the range of an integer, you could do the usual multiply by 100, truncate, modify based on lsd, divide by 100. You could even do it if it does, but extracting the mantissa will be trickier, not to mention putting it back. But why are you using floating point arithmetic on a microcontroller to begin with?

Comment: Are `sprintf` and `atof` available?

Comment: You can't actually round to 1 decimal place as floating point is binary. here is no exact representation of 0.1. Depending what you want to do, it might be best to round to the nearest 0.125.

Comment: Okay, so what if you just call `LCD_display_float(Temp, 1)`?

Comment: If I assign a value myself of 1 decimal place such as "10.2", the lcd shows it fine. But the result of Temp passed out from this function, LCD displays "ERR".

Comment: @ammoQ No they are not available

Comment: @Mohsin It might be displaying "ERR" for some other reason.  I doubt it's giving you an error because you're passing a number that's not already rounded.  What if you assign a value yourself like 10.23 or "10.234?

Comment: @Mohsin It might help to see `LCD_display_float()`, if it's not too big.

Comment: It appears `LCD_display_float ()` does the rounding for you.  Just call it `LCD_display_float (Temp, 1);`

Comment: Note: I am certain OP's 1023.0 is incorrect and should be 1024 due to an incorrect understanding of the A/D conversion results.

Answer (score 2):

The usual solution on microcontrollers is to **not** do this. Decimal places are for humans, and that sort of luxury doesn't belong on embedded hardware. Heck, even binary floating point is a bit of a luxury.

The only place where you might see decimal math is in I/O operations. For those cases, it's easiest to internally work with an integer. So the range `0.0 - 6553.5` is internally represented as `0-65535`. On output, you just print `value/10 . value%10`.

Comment: @Mohsin: I wouldn't bother with that function, or `float` in general.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to do this is to scale, add 0.5, truncate, and un-scale:

```
float x;

...

x *= 10;
x = (int)(x + 0.5);
x /= 10;
```

Or, in one line:

```
x = (int)(x * 10 + 0.5) / 10.;
```

By adding 0.5 before truncating to int, you arrange that numbers with a fractional part greater than 0.5 round up.

But there are two other points to consider:

1. This simple, basic rounding recipe will *not* handle negative numbers correctly.
2. Floating-point numbers on most computers can't represent decimal fractions exactly.  So you haven't *really* rounded `x` to "one place past the decimal".  If you print `x` out later, you'll often find that it seems to contain a number like, say, 3.199999 instead of 3.2.  There's nothing you can do about this; the usual solution is to use a printf format like `%.1f` when it comes time to print the number out.  And once you're using a printf format like `%.1f`, it'll do all the rounding for you, so you don't have to.

So the question is, what are you actually doing with your floating-point numbers that they have to be rounded to "one place past the decimal"?  Are you printing them out as a string, or doing something else with them?  And if you're printing them out, are you using printf or something else?